# what does size do when adding index in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql

What does size do exactly? Sorry, I'm quite new to MySQL. What I understand so far is that size is for the maximum integer count for the column? Say if my size is 4, then the integer limit would be 9999. Is that how it works? 
Here's a picture for what I'm referring:
[image]

Comment: Read the documentation of [`CREATE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

Comment: If you would like to use integer as your id, then why did you create the field as varchar? Varchar is for storing text.

Comment: This question is about phpMyAdmin, not the SQL syntax, so to call this a duplicate of a question that refers only to the SQL syntax, where the documentation describes it as "length" not "size", is lame IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can create an index on the leading characters of a column. this is called *prefix index*

For instance this :

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

Will create an index only the first 10 characters of the `name` column

Here you have asked phpmyadmin to define your column `en_id` as PRIMARY KEY, and by default it shows you the length of the column, which is 4 char, to index it entirely.

You should probably not touch this for a primary key on a such short number of chars.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html):

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates
>   the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example,
>   CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.

So yes, in your case it can hold 4 digits maximum; i.e. 9999.

Comment: The question was about the index, not the field itself.

Comment: Excellent answer, precisely the information I was searching for! Tanks! 